# Call Celery class-based task in sync mode

Tags: python, celery, django-celery

I have celery class-based task

```
from celery import Task
from django.db import transaction

from config import celery_app


class RefreshData(Task):
    name = "refresh-data"

    @transaction.atomic
    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        SomeClass().some_fuc()

celery_app.register_task(RefreshData)
```

Now I want to run it in sync mode (in tests). How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to `mock.patch` the call of the task in such way, as we call it in sync.

To call task in sync `RefreshData().run(*args, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 0):

By setting **task_always_eager** to **True**, tasks will be executed immediately (synchronously) instead of being sent to the queue (asynchronously), allowing you to debug the code within the task.

**task_always_eager** is **False** by default to help prevent inadvertently activating it in production.

reference https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html?highlight=task_always_eager#std-setting-task_always_eager

Comment: I'm not sure it is correct. See https://celeryproject.readthedocs.io/zh_CN/v4.2.0_docs/userguide/testing.html#tasks-and-unit-tests
Maybe you can provide a code example?

Comment: wrong link, https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/testing.html

Comment: Updated the link. Celery links seems to have updated over past few days.

Comment: I mean, why should I change settings to run a task? Maybe there is proper way? Like, for example, for celery tasks with `shared decorator`

Comment: During the tests phase you can update the settings to run in single thread

Comment: From the official doc https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/testing.html - The eager mode enabled by the task_always_eager setting is by definition not suitable for unit tests.